# What's the most concise way to check for an integer or float in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, types

I want a concise expression to tell me if a given value is an integer or float. When provided the input value `NaN` or `Infinity`, I want the output value to be false, so this rules out simply checking whether `typeof(val) == 'number'`

Desired input / output:

- `1` => `true`
- `-42` => `true`
- `3.14` => `true`
- `NaN` => `false`
- `Infinity` => `false`
- `null` => `false`
- `undefined` => `false`

`isFinite()` is almost perfect, but there's one gotcha: `isFinite(null)` returns true, when I actually want it to return false.

Short of always checking `if ((val != nul) && isFinite(val))`, is there another more concise technique?

Comment: `if !isNaN(value)` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @Abbath, that doesn't work.  `null` returns as `false`; when doing `Number(null)`, the result is `0`.

Comment: @Abbath `!isNan(Infinity)` returns `true`

Comment: @ps2goat it will fail for 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// As suggested in the comments, a function:
var isNumber = function (val) {return !isNaN(parseInt(val))};
console.log(isNumber(1)) // true
console.log(isNumber(-42)) // true
console.log(isNumber(3.14)) // true
console.log(isNumber(NaN)) // false
console.log(isNumber(Infinity)) // false
console.log(isNumber(null)) // false
console.log(isNumber(undefined)) // false
```

Comment: You may even want to write a `isNumber` function: `var isNumber = function (val) {return !isNan(parseInt(val))}`